# how to order the objects in the dope sheet

Tags: dopesheet

Is there a way to order the objects in the dope sheet. I know you can move the channels up with the <kbd>page up</kbd> button and down with <kbd>page down</kbd> button. But this doesn't work with the objects, is there a way to do this?

[image]

Comment: This question really need to be revived. Someone put a bounty?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround for more oversight, you could click the little arrow in the dopesheet footer (little arrow | ghost | rescue ring), to only display the currently selected objects. select different objects in the viewport or the outliner.

Comment: Yes I know that function, but i want to see all the objects in a specific order so i can easily offset keyframes.

Comment: ah i dont know then :(.

Answer (score 1):

You double click the object name on the left and by changing it's name you can order it alphabetically and numerically. Cube.001 is above Cube.002.
It takes some time but there really is no other convenient way and this actually helps organize your scene! :)

Answer (score 1):

In the Dope Sheet Editor Type. There is a option called Move, under Channel. You can move the Dope Sheet channels by either accessing that selection. Or through the shortcut *Page Up* or *page down* to move it in it's respective description when selecting the specific channel.

[image]